# How to create pivot table in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel-4

I have a database table `teacher_attendances`, with field:

`id, name, data, attendance`.

I try to generate a pivot table based on `teacher_attendances` table.

I want `rowname`  as `TeacherName` and `columnname` as `Date` and `cloumnname` below mark attendance.

How to create pivot table in Laravel 4?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked out [Laravel Migration](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/migrations) and [Schema Builder](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema) Documentation?

Run `php artisan migrate:make create_teacher_attendances_table --create --table=teacher_attendances` in the CLI to generate the file.

Then edit the file to include something like this **up** method

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teacher_attendances', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        // Your code here
    });
}
```

Don't forget about [foreign-keys](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema#foreign-keys).

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute following command:

```
php artisan make:migration create_attendance_teacher --table="attendance_teacher"
```

> **Note :** `create_attendance_teacher` is taken singular form for the tables ***attendances*** & ***teachers*** respectively.
>   
>  As per convention try to create pivot table alphabetical order. Hence we took ***attendance table*** before ***teachers table.***

Then, in migration script:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('teacher_attendances', function(Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('attendance_id');//Foreign key from attendances table
        $table->increments('teacher_id');////Foreign key from teachers table
    });
}
```